# Why should I use private at this point?

Tags: java, class, private

I am learning Java right now with an Udemy Course, everything made sense until now.
The coach showed this code as explaination for the private class usage in Java.

```
public class Hero {

    public String name;
    private int healthpoints;

    public Hero(int healthpoints){
        if (healthpoints <=  100 && healthpoints > 0){
            this.healthpoints = healthpoints;
        } else{
            this.healthpoints = 90;
        }
    }

    public void getHealthpoints(){
        System.out.println(this.healthpoints);
    }

    public void setHealthpoints(int damage){
        this.healthpoints -= damage;
        System.out.println(this.healthpoints);
    }
}
```

And the main methode looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Hero player = new Hero(-57);
        player.getHealthpoints();
    }
}
```

I understand the whole code, that's not the issue, but why do I need `private` at `int healthpoints`? I can literally change the value with `setHealthpoints` or just put `public int Healthpoints`. It doesn't make sense to me, can someone explain why private should be used there? The purpose of private is that other class don't have access to it, right?

Comment: It is to maintain encapsulation -- you can thereby fully control how or if the field is changed and accessed, including filtering input, restricting output, if need be.

Comment: Note that your `setHealthpoints` does not actually do what it says. Instead, it's `takeDamage`. In fact, it's impossible to regain HP in your code (and `private` makes this enforceable policy).

Comment: Here's the way I'd describe it to a beginner. Imagine I hand you a class to use and it has hundreds of private fields and methods, but only a single public method. Now imagine I hand you a class to use and it has hundreds of public fields and methods. Which do you imagine will be easier to use? The class with one button/dial/switch, or the class with hundreds?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- impossible?  `setHealthpoints(-9999)`

Comment: @Vincenzo - You're right; making a member private and then providing what is essentially an unvalidated setter does not afford any protection.  There might be more point if there was some validation, e.g., protecting against negative 'damage' (not withstanding previous comments that it's not really a setter), making sure the values were in a legal range, and so on.  There's still a minor benefit in larger programs - you can perhaps more readily add validation later, maybe you decide that package access is more suitable than public, or whatever.  But unconstrained setters do not stop misuse.